# French Defense ECO C00 game for analysis

Tags: analysis, french-defense

Here is the game for analysis which had been played between two matured person.

```
[fen ""]
1.e4 e6 2.d3 g6 3.f3 Bg7 4.g4 a5 5.h3 a4 6.b3 a3 7.Nxa3 Bxa1 8.Bd2 Rxa3 9.Qxa1 f6 10.Qc1 Rxa2 11.Qb1 Ra3 12. Qc1 Ra6 13.Qb1 Ra3 14.Qb2 Ra6 15.f4 b5 16.f5 c5 17.Be3 Qb6 18.Bc1 b4 19.c3 d6 20.d4 Ra3 21.Qb1 Ra5 --
```

This game had withdrawn due to this wrong move,- `22.h5` observed at the time scribbling. The person who made this move not only a very good artist but very good person in many kind. That person knows many thing which me,- the other person not aware of.

Saying or commenting about the game as part of analysis, make a note abt. what is fascinating overall.

Why did I moved `3.* Bg7 4. g4 a5 ...`

Comment: When you say this is a game between "two matured person" I can only imagine the players are adults, because the players are obviously absolute beginners in terms of playing strength.

Comment: Majors within a family.

Answer (score 1):

Putting all your pawns on one type of square color is usually not a good idea. For instance black could have played 4 .. Qh4+. Also with all the pawns on light squares the bishop on g7 gets incredibly strong.

Generally too many pawn moves in the opening from both sides. Should have developed pieces.

Few bad moves:

- 6. b3?? blunders the rook which black should take already here
- 8. .. Rxa3? I would not exchange this very powerful bishop for the knight on a3. Better to retreat the bishop to g7.
- Not sure why black insists putting the rook on a3 in moves 11 and 13. Not much to attack there and the rook could always easily be attacked.Nothing wrong with retreating to a8 for the time being. The main duty of the rook is to occupy the open a file which it does equally well from a8.